# Modifying network state programatically on Android?

Tags: android, networking

I'd like to build an application to modify the network state on certain events in the system. How could I disable anything above 2G networking? I'd really like to be able to disable all 3G, WiFi, 4G (WiMax/LTE) whenever a given event happens. I can take care of listening for these events, but how can I change the network settings? What permissions would I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only firmware, or SDK apps signed with the firmware signing key, would have a shot at doing this.

Comment: Bummer! That's really lame, I thought for sure there would be a way to do this. Trying to make a battery-saver application.